# Do you have to play The Witness twice to solve the last puzzle?

Tags: the-witness

This whole question is a spoiler, so I ask it all hidden:

> When you start the game, the tower at the exit gate of the first castle is glowing white, so you can solve that puzzle. But once you solve the puzzle to open the gate, it stops glowing and you cannot solve that puzzle any more and cannot finish the monolith in the village.C
>
>  Do I have to solve this puzzle right at the start to be able to solve the monolith in the village?
>
> Or is there a way to reactivate the glowing gate-pole?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can reactive the glowing gate.

> In the cave-system leading to The Challenge, you find sheets of paper with the same pattern as the the puzzle next to the gate.  Enter that pattern to reactivate the gate.

Comment: And if activated, how can you deactivate it again to walk out of the starting castle again? I solved 514 puzzles in my current state, but cannot get out again to solve the rest. the last savegame before was at 498 puzzles

Comment: I found it, I just had to reload the last savegame, standing right before the gate and solve the triangle puzzle again in the old way

Answer (score 1):

It seems, there is a solution within only one game run.

> I saw the beginning of a [Video](https://steamcommunity.com/app/210970/discussions/4/412446292754871228/), how you can solve the puzzle at the gate, to reactivate the glowing pole.

I don't want to spoil myself, so I didn't watch the whole solution myself either ;)