# Is it possible for an environmental puzzle to be no longer solvable?

Tags: the-witness

I'm playing The Witness for the first time. I've discovered the "environmental puzzles", but I have also found something that seems like it would be one, but is uncompletable given the current game state:

> In the starting area, there is a glowing column that you eventually turn off along with the forcefield to allow exiting the area. I now think this was very likely an environmental puzzle and I would have been able to align the glowing column with the *sun* as the start of the path. But I can't find a way to reactivate the column.

1. Are there *any* environmental puzzles that can be rendered uncompletable?
2. Is the one I have referred to in the spoiler blocks one of them?
3. If not, then could you provide a hint as to how it should be completed despite the seemingly missing essential ingredient?

Picture supplement to the description:

> [image: The sun aligned on top of the unlit pillar]

Comment: Related: [Do you have to play The Witness twice to solve the last puzzle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263688/do-you-have-to-play-the-witness-twice-to-solve-the-last-puzzle)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they're all possible.  That one in particular is extremely special.
Minor spoilers:

> It becomes possible to reset it later in the game

Major spoilers!

> After beating the game, you find a way of turning that column back on, which leads to the secret ending